# Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: rejected master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, github, initialization, githooks

I have a fresh repository on a github organization page where I'm trying to do an initial push of an existing code base. When I do, I get the following error:

> Opening repositories: 
> D:\OneDrive\MyOrg\DevTeam\myFeature 
> Commit abcd123 created locally in repository D:\OneDrive\MyOrg\DevTeam\myFeature 
> Pushing master 
> Enumerating objects: 12310, done. 
> Delta compression using up to 8 threads 
> POST git-receive-pack (chunked) 
> Total 12310 (delta 8123), reused 0 (delta 0) 
> Pushing to https://github.com/MyOrg/myOrganization.git 
> To https://github.com/MyOrg/myOrganization.git 
> failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MyOrg/myOrganization.git' 
> Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: rejected master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

I've changed the names for obvious reasons, and I'm not too familiar with hooks. I did read from the following link on pre-receive server side hooks and what they are though:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks
and it appears to be a thing that the server side changes the rights or requirements to being able to push I believe? However, the github page and repo in itself are both fresh and untouched, so I'm not sure how these hooks would even be adjusted (even if I could, which idk if I can).

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard pre-receive hook on a bare GitHub repo, it must have been installed by your company ([GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.19/user/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/working-with-pre-receive-hooks)).

Check with your company what rules they have enforced ; you may suggest them to add some more explicit messages to explain rejection.

Comment: Ah ok that's good to know. The company is actually really small and I'm one of the only three devs in the company so I actually would theoretically be the one enforcing these rules as I'm the one that created the github organization page and repo. Where would one theoretically set these pre-receive hooks?

Comment: Sorry just to add I actally just took a look at [this github doc](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.19/admin/developer-workflow/using-pre-receive-hooks-to-enforce-policy) in regards to creating pre-receive hooks and I've never done any of this (I'm essentially the github repo admin), how would I go about removing these hooks if I'm not even aware of them being in place?

Comment: Ask around if someone knows about some "company rules" or if "the person that manage(d) the repo set some specific hook". Otherwise, dig into the docs : 2 clicks from the link above lead to [this page](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.19/admin/developer-workflow/managing-pre-receive-hooks-on-the-github-enterprise-server-appliance)

Comment: Well I'm the one who created the repo, so there's no one previous to me that's ever managed the repo which is what I meant by I'd theoretically be the one who enforces/creates these rules. I then made my coworker owner of the page, so maybe he added a script/hook without realizing. Thank you for the link! I will ask him to make me owner so I can do some digging.

Comment: Actually one more question, I noticed that it says pre-receive hooks for Github Enterprise. Are the hooks a functionality only for Enterprise? We are currently using free. So I would be pretty lost if it's only for Enterprise but we're not even Enterprise.

Comment: I saw `/MyOrg/` in your urls, so I assumed it was an enterprise account. Ask GitHub support otherwise.

Comment: Ah ok yea /MyOrg/ is just the companies name and I didn't want to publicly post it. The page is just from "new organization" for Github. Are pre-receive hooks typically a feature limited to Enterprise accounts or would all account types be able to access it?